# File copy too slow when pyqt is involved

Tags: python, performance, pyqt

I am using this code (very simplified version of original but problem remains) to copy a file:

```
def copyfileobj_example(source, dest, buffer_size=1024*1024):
    while 1:
        copy_buffer = source.read(buffer_size)
        if not copy_buffer:
            break
        dest.write(copy_buffer)
```

If I call the function without pyqt the files are copied realy fast, but when I call it inside a simple pyqt window, the copy is three times slower.

Copy fast a huge number of files is the main point of the application, I assume that including the gui will slow things a little, but no make it three times slower!! and running the copy function using threads or multiprocess do not cause satisfactory improvements.

This is just as is? could you recommendme something to solve this performance issue?

EDIT: [There](https://gist.github.com/cccaballero/83a7bd86c05b2f3f6497) is a gist with my actual copy code, running with and without PyQT

Comment: Please provide a complete pyqt example that demonstrates the problem. I am unable to reproduce this using PyQt-4.11.4 with python 3.5 on Linux.

Comment: Added some test code, using PyQT 5.4.1 and python 2.7

Comment: I had trouble running your example. Please try the test case in my answer and confrim whether you see the same problem.

Comment: @ekhumoro you use python 2.7? with python 3.x it fails in some place with the multiprocessing

Comment: I managed to get the code to run, but it's horribly inefficient. With my example code, it takes 3 seconds to copy a 400MB file, but with yours, it takes over 10 seconds. What exactly are you trying to achieve with that multiprocessing stuff? Python IO is generally very fast (not much different from equivalent C code), so why do think you need all the extra complications?

Comment: the idea is copy faster to multiple hdd reducing IO (read one time and write to all) the multiprocessing is used to try to write to all destinations at same time. The tests show a considerable improvement when copy to multiple destinations (except when PyQT appears)

Comment: @ekhumoro I make some [tests](https://gist.github.com/cccaballero/6821fb1ad1223ea5ede0) with a 1.5 gb file without PyQT and there is not so much difference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably an effect of the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). With PyQt running in the UI thread, it "steals" the GIL every time it has to handle events. That means your loop above stops every time. This also happens when you're running in another thread; the lock is *global*.

Workarounds:

1. Use a larger buffer. The C layer of Python isn't affected by the GIL, so if you copy larger amounts of data, the commands in the loop are executed less often.
2. Execute an external command to do the copying (possibly another Python process).
3. Use Qt's IO classes to copy the file since the aren't affected by the GIL either (Kudos to [ekhumoro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984421/ekhumoro) for the idea).
4. Write a piece of code in C which transfers the data.
5. Use a version of Python which doesn't have a GIL like IronPython or Jython.

Comment: You mean that if I write the copy function as a c extension, I can solve the problem?

Comment: @Cesar. Before you go off on a wild-goose chase, I should point out that I am unable to reproduce your issue. Using PyQt-4.11.4 on Linux, the copy operation takes exactly the same time. I seriously doubt whether this has anything to do with the GIL, since IO bound operations are completely unaffected by it. But in any case, if you want to eliminate python from the equation, just do the copy operation using the Qt IO classes.

Comment: @ekhumoro: Good suggestion about the IO classes. The loop is so simple that the GIL is about the only thing which could cause the effect. Note that on Windows, Qt has to process a lot of events to make the OS happy.

Comment: @AaronDigulla. Looking at the OPs profile, it would seem they are using ubuntu. But in any case, do you really think a **three-times** slow down is plausible? Just how many *billion* events would have to be processed to produce that kind of effect? If what you claim was really true, it would be a very, very serious limitation of pyqt. Needless to say, I think you need to back up your claims with some hard evidence (e.g. some testable example code).

Comment: Right now the copy execution times for a 1.5 gb file in my system are ~21 seconds without PyQT and ~35 seconds with a PyQT window, the first tests maybe were affected for a hdd indexing process, there still is a considerable performance problem

Comment: @ekhumoro: I agree with your analysis but I also can't see any other reason why the loop above should be so slow. Maybe he has a defective USB HID device.

Answer (score 2):

Since I am unable to get the linked code in the question to work (it just hangs and uses 100% CPU), I will post a saner example for the purposes of testing.

Using the test case below, I get the following output when copying a 400MB file (three runs):

```
$ python copy_test.py
2.9546546936035156
2.9658050537109375
$ python copy_test.py
3.226983070373535
3.192814826965332
$ python copy_test.py
2.935734748840332
2.8552770614624023
```

As you can see, there is no significant difference. For clarity, this was using the following setup on Linux:

```
Python 3.5.0, Qt 5.5.0, PyQt 5.5
```

and I get similar results with all combinations of Python 2.7/3.5, PyQt 4/5.

Here is the test case:

```
import sys
import time
import os

SRC_FILE = '/home/tmp/source/test/test.zip'
DEST_FILE = '/home/tmp/source/test/test-copy.zip'

def copy_file(src, dst=[], progress=None, only_new_file=True):
    size = 1024 * 1024
    with open(src, 'rb') as s, open(dst[0], 'wb') as d:
        while 1:
            copy_buffer = s.read(size)
            if not copy_buffer:
                break
            d.write(copy_buffer)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    initTime = time.time()
    copy_file(SRC_FILE, [DST_FILE], only_new_file=False)
    print (time.time() - initTime)

    time.sleep(5)

    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
#     from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QWidget

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QWidget()
    w.resize(250, 150)
    w.move(300, 300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
    w.show()

    initTime = time.time()
    copy_file(SRC_FILE, [DST_FILE], only_new_file=False)
    print (time.time() - initTime)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I take my time to install a new and fresh system to make some tests, I don't know what was interfering in my system, now there is no delay doing the normal copy, but appear when the multiprocessing is involved

Comment: @Cesar. Using your multiprocessing example, try with just the pyqt import line and nothing else. If you still see a delay, this should prove that the problem is somehow caused by multiprocessing. In which case, I would suggest you switch to using a multi-threading approach instead. If you use `QThread`, this should also make integration with the GUI much simpler.

Comment: yes!! replacing multiprocessing by threading solves the delay problem, but why? i used multiprocessing to try to benefit from multi core processors, and everything goes fine until I add pyqt

Comment: @Cesar. At the moment, it's hard to say where the problem lies. Have you tested with PySide? If you see the same behaviour, then it suggests the source of the problem lies in either Qt or Python, rather than PyQt/PySide. Maybe there is some obscure GIL-related issue after all, or perhaps there's some other multiprocessing weirdness related to importing or forking. If you really want to get a proper answer to this, though, I think the only way is to post some bug reports to the relevant channels (possibly starting with the python bug tracker).